# sed strip leading mixed text up to some character

Tags: regex, sed

I have a line like this:

**14:32:38,723 [some text] ERROR - some more text .....**.

I want to delete everything right up to (but not including) the first "[" (so that the result is a line that begins with [some text] .....)

My reading of

```
's/^.*\d*\s//'
```

is that it should replace everything up a digit followed by a space, but it appears to be applying the replace everywhere in the line i.e. being greedy.

I've tried:

```
's/^.*\s\[//g'
```

but it's stripping that first "["

How do I modify either expression to do what I need?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would apply the following sed command

```
s/^[^[]*\[/\[/
```

It replaces everything up to the first `[` with a single `[`.

```
$ echo "14:32:38,723 [some text] ERROR - some more" | sed 's/^[^[]*\[/\[/'
[some text] ERROR - some more text
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/[^[]*//' file
```